# Filling in timeseries based on matching hour/minute between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I'm trying to create a dataframe with a year's worth of data based on a single day's worth of data. All my data is at minute-level frequency. To do this, I've made a new dataframe using pandas date_range function to create the index:

`df_fullyear = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2029-01-01', end='2030-01-01', freq='T', closed='left'))`

From there, I want to copy over values from my single day dataframe based on matching hours/minutes--e.g., whenever it's 4:00 in my full year dataframe, I want to have the value at 4:00 from my single day dataframe. The following is my attempt to match the two dataframes--it definitely doesn't work, but I can't think of a more elegant way to do this without looping through each hour and each minute and assigning the full-year df bit by bit.

`(df_fullyear.index.hour == dfs[2029].index.hour) & (df_fullyear.index.minute == dfs[2029].index.minute)`

What's the most pythonic way to do this matching on hour/minute between dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

You could repeat the values from the daily data like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_fullyear = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range(
        start='2029-01-01',
        end='2030-01-01',
        freq='T',
        closed='left'))
day_data = pd.Series(
    index=pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", freq="T", closed="left"),
    data=np.random.randn(24 * 60))
num_days, rem = divmod(len(df_fullyear), len(day_data))
assert rem == 0
values = np.tile(day_data.values, num_days)
df_fullyear['mycol'] = values

print(df_fullyear[
    (df_fullyear.index.minute==0) & (df_fullyear.index.hour==4)])
```

Output:

```
                        mycol
2029-01-01 04:00:00 -0.646003
2029-01-02 04:00:00 -0.646003
...
```